# Overloading Based on L-Value versus R-Value

Tags: c++, overloading

I found in a C++ book the following:

> Although we will not be doing it in this book, you can overload a
>   function name (or operator) so that it behaves differently when used
>   as an l-value and when it is used as an r-value. (Recall that an
>   l-value means it can be used on the left-hand side of an assignment
>   statement.) For example, if you want a function f to behave
>   differently depending on whether it is used as an l-value or an
>   r-value, you can do so as follows:

```
class SomeClass { 
public:
  int& f(); // will be used in any l-value invocation const 
  const int& f( ) const; // used in any r-value invocation ... 
};
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
class Foo {
        public:
        int& id(int& a);
        const int& id(int& a) const;
};

int main() {
        int a;
        Foo f;
        f.id(a) = 2;
        a = f.id(a);
        cout << f.id(a) << endl;
}

int& Foo :: id(int& a) {
        cout << "Bar\n";
        return a;
}

const int& Foo :: id(int& a) const {
        cout << "No bar !\n";
        return a;
}
```

Have I wrongly understood it ?

Comment: AFAIK A function overload cannot differ by just return type alone

Comment: @PaulRenton: No, but they can differ in const-ness, as the code shows.

Answer (score 3):

Either the book's example is flat-out wrong, or you copied the wrong example from the book.

```
class SomeClass { 
public:
  int& f(); // will be used in any l-value invocation const 
  const int& f( ) const; // used in any r-value invocation ... 
};
```

With this code, when you call `s.f()` where `s` is an object of type `SomeClass`, the first version will be called when `s` is non-`const`, and the second version will be called when `s` is `const`. Value category has nothing to do with it.

Ref-qualification looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class SomeClass {
public:
  int f() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
  int f() && { std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
};
int main() {
    SomeClass s; s.f(); // prints "lvalue"
    SomeClass{}.f(); // prints "rvalue"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse the book is [correct](http://ideone.com/KoPu6f). Let me explain the workings of an example of what the author meant :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CO
{
    int _m;
public:
    CO(int m) : _m(m) {}
    int& m()             { return _m; } // used as an l-value
    int const& m() const { return _m; } // used as an r-value
};

int main() 
{
    CO a(1);
    
    cout << a.m() << endl;
    
    a.m() = 2; // here used as an l-value / overload resolution selects the correct one
    
    cout << a.m() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

> 1
>
> 2

What you misunderstood is the function signature. You see when you have an argument `&arg` (as in `id(&arg)`) you pretty much predefine the l-valuness of it, so returning it through a const or non const member function does not change a thing.

The author refers to a common writting style that allows for 'getters' and 'setters' to be declared with a signature different only in `const` qualifires **yet compile and behave correctly.**

**Edit**

To be more pedantic, the following phrase

> *Recall that an l-value means it can be used on the left-hand side of an assignment statement.*

is not valid anymore. *lr* valuness applies to expressions, and the shortest way to explain it, is that an expression whose adress we can take, is an l-value; if it's not obtainable it's an r-value.

So the syntax to which the author refers to, enforces the member function to be used correctly  (correct compilation / overload resolution) at both sides of the assignment operator. This nowdays is no longer relevant to *lr* valueness.

Comment: No, the book is wrong because it mixes const-ness with lr-value-ness. These are different concepts. Maybe the difference was not so important in C++98, but now, in C++11 it is, because now you can actually overload upon lr-value-ness of an object, as Brian's answer illustrates.

Comment: @rodrigo That is the context to which the book is reffering, and the example is the common use case. From a standardese point of view you are correct, but OP had his use case figured out wrong, so just pointing a correct use. Do you think this [use case - see `x()`](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/C_plus_plus:Tutorials:TemplateVector) will break code when c++11 kicks in ?

Comment: I don't see why it would break. It is a standard const-ness overload. C++11 is mostly backwards compatible, so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I tried it here http://ideone.com/0Bam6V with a slight modification, and, apparently, the "const" variant is never called. In what context is the compiler going to invoke that method ?

Answer (score 0):

A `const` member function can only be called on a const object. It makes no difference what you do with the return value. In your example, f is non-const, so it always calls the non-const version of `f()`. Note that you can also overload on r-value references (`&&`) in C++11.